# Setting Toolbar Items

Tags: iphone

I try to set toolbar items in the navigationcontrollers top view. Seems to work in the subviews... but why not in the top view...any ideas? I get the add button... but not my custom button.

```
- (void)configureToolbarItems {
UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                  target:self action:@selector(addNewTaskButtonPressed)];   

//Green button
greenButton=[app makeGreenButton:self];
UIBarButtonItem *greenBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:greenButton];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

// Set our toolbar items    
[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       addButtonItem,flexibleSpace, greenBarButton, nil] animated:YES]; }
```

This is the makeButton procedure... works fine in other views:

```
-(UIButton*)makeGreenButton:(UIViewController*)caller {
UIButton *greenButton;
//load the image for yellow button
UIImage *greenButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenButton.png"];    
//create the button and assign the image
greenButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[greenButton setImage:greenButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
greenButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=TRUE; 
//set the frame of the button to the size of the image (see note below)
greenButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, greenButtonImage.size.width*2, greenButtonImage.size.height*2);
//Add target
[greenButton addTarget:caller action:@selector(greenButtonReleased:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return greenButton; }
```

Comment: Which are the frame of the greenButton after its creation?

Comment: Do you mean frame size? 40x40. Image is 20x20.

Comment: Do you try to wrap the greenButton with a UIView?

Comment: The code works very well in one view... Is there anything special about the top view in a nav controller?

Comment: Found a similar problem below. Now I can get the icon to show... I have no idea why...yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349591/uinavigationcontrollers-toolbar-with-custom-items